# Image of a line under a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Can anyone please let me know if I did something wrong?

Let $L$ be a line on the complex plane. Find its image under $f(z) =\sqrt{z}$ when:

1. $L$ is horizontal.
2. $L$ is vertical.
3. $L$ is given by the equation $y=x\sqrt{3}$.

I started by writing $w^2=z$. Then replacing $z=x+yi$ and $w=u+vi$. Thus I get

$$u^2-v^2+2uvi=x+yi. $$

In the first case, $z\in L$ means that $z=x+0i$. It follows that

$$u^2-v^2=x$$

which represents a hyperbola.

If $L$ is vertical, then $z\in L$ is the same of $z=yi$. Consequently,

$$2uv=y, $$

That it represents a hyperbola too.

Finally, an element in 3rd case is just like 
$z=x+x\sqrt{3} i$. So,
$$u^2-v^2=x,\ 2uv=x\sqrt{3} . $$
And I can't go on from this point.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: In the first case, to have the imaginary part zero, either $u$ or $v$ needs to be zero, which is much more in agreement with what you see if you draw the line on a paper. ;-) Similarly, in the second case you want $u=\pm v$ to have the real part zero, so that's a 45 degree line. So this tells you what happens: you will always get a line with half the slope, and that answers case 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $w=u\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\alpha}$ and $z=v\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\beta}$. Then $w^2=z$ implies that either
$$ w=\sqrt{z}\quad\text{and}\quad \alpha=\beta/2$$
or
$$ w=-\sqrt{z}\quad\text{and}\quad \alpha=\beta/2+\pi/2\;.$$
So the slopes of the image line is half of the slope of the original line modulo $\pi/2$. In the first case, the image is either a horizontal or vertical line, in the second case, these are the 45 and 135 degree lines and in the last case the slope is either $\sqrt{3}/2$ or the line perpendicular to that one.